# Why is Max function returning rows with a value of 0

Tags: sql, max, where-clause

Could anyone tell me why the following query seems to return rows with the percentage value of 0 where they exist.

```
SELECT cl.countrycode, c.name, c.continent, cl.language
FROM country c
JOIN countrylanguage cl ON cl.countrycode = c.code
WHERE Percentage = ANY (SELECT MAX(Percentage) FROM countrylanguage GROUP BY countrycode)
```

I could add ' && percentage > 0' to the query to filter these out but the MAX function should only be filtering the max percentage for each countrycode?

Comment: Because some country code has a max percentage of 0, presumably. You haven't explained what the query is supposed to do, but it probably doesn't do that.

Comment: Where a country has a language with the percentage of 0 as well as others it includes the MAX row and the row with 0.

The idea of this query is to find the most common language in each country.

Comment: right, it doesn't do that. Look at the `ANY`. It returns any row where the percentage is equal *any* country's max percentage, not *that* country's max percentage.

Comment: I'm struggling to follow, to help me understand could you advise what on the query should be to get the desired results?

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT cl.countrycode, c.name, c.continent, cl.language
FROM country c JOIN
     countrylanguage cl
     ON cl.countrycode = c.code
WHERE Percentage = ANY (SELECT MAX(Percentage)
                        FROM countrylanguage
                        GROUP BY countrycode
                       );
```

The subquery returns *all* percentages that are the maximum value for *any* country.  Some countries could have a row where `0` is the maximum value.   You can run the query independently to see this.

The outer query then finds any percentage that matches the maximum for *any* country.  That really doesn't make sense.

What you want is the maximum *per country*.  For that, use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT cl.countrycode, c.name, c.continent, cl.language
FROM country c JOIN
     countrylanguage cl
     ON cl.countrycode = c.code
WHERE cl.Percentage = (SELECT MAX(cl2.Percentage)
                       FROM countrylanguage cl2
                       WHERE cl2.countrycode = cl.countrycode
                      );
```

The difference is that the subquery now has a `WHERE` clause rather than a `GROUP BY` clause, mandating that the countries be the same.

Comment: Hi, thanks, your query achieves what i want.

You mention the following,

"The subquery returns all percentages that are the maximum value for any country. Some countries could have a row where 0 is the maximum value. You can run the query independently to see this."

This doesnt seem to be the case, in nearly all cases it gets the language with the highest percentage for each country as desired. The only time this doesnt work is when some languages for particular countries have a percentage set to 0, so it will include the actual max but also any rows with zero, why is this the case?

Comment: @JackFurniss . . . A good approximation of the explanation is that  the only overlaps with values *between* countries is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

try modifying like this;

```
SELECT cl.countrycode, c.name, c.continent, cl.language
FROM country c
JOIN countrylanguage cl ON cl.countrycode = c.code
WHERE Percentage = (SELECT MAX(Percentage) FROM countrylanguage cl2 where cl2.countrycode=cl.countrycode)
```